# anytime function (anytime package) to capture days and month correcly

Tags: r

I have the following character `"07.01.2009 22:40:00"` where 07 is the day and 01 the month. When I call `anytime("07.01.2009 22:40:00")` it returns `"2009-07-01 22:40:00 -03"` as if 07 is the month. Is there any way I tell this function that 07 is the day and not the month?

Comment: This format seems to be commented out https://github.com/eddelbuettel/anytime/blob/master/src/anytime.cpp#L51, I'd guess as its kind of difficult to have arule when comparing to the us style of dates

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `strptime` from `base R`

```
strptime('07.01.2009 22:40:00', format = '%d.%m.%Y %T', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2009-01-07 22:40:00 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you can specify specific formats in `anytime` but here are two alternatives :

1. Using `lubridate` :

```
lubridate::dmy_hms('07.01.2009 22:40:00')
#[1] "2009-01-07 22:40:00 UTC"
```

2. Using base R :

```
as.POSIXct('07.01.2009 22:40:00', format = '%d.%m.%Y %T', tz = 'UTC')
#[1] "2009-01-07 22:40:00 UTC"
```

Comment: Sure, I had already managed to do it on Lubridate. Thank you anyway. I was just curious because I like to use anytime more often and I don't see why they wouldn't include it as a feature in this package.